# How to use different config.xml for different Phonegap Targets in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, cordova

I want to have multiple targets in my Phonegap Xcode project that share resources but load from a different index.html file.

The index file that is loaded is determined by the config.xml file.

How can I define a different config.xml file or a different index.html file for these different targets.

Alternatively, is there a better way to apply settings, and deploy an app that is 99.9% the same?

I'm using Cordova 2.8.1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap's `CDVViewController.m` reads `config.xml` from the main bundle, so you can

1. Create a separate directory for each target.
2. Create a `config.xml` for each target in the associated directory from step 1.
3. Use the Target Membership panel in Xcode's Utilities view to set the target membership of each `config.xml` from step 2 to the correct target.

If the only difference is the starting HTML file, you could modify your `AppDelegate.m` and use a compile-time constant to define the starting page:

```
self.viewController.startPage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", START_HTML_FILE];
```

To set the compile time constant, go into Build Phases tab in Xcode *for each target* and use the `-D` compiler flag. For example:

```
-DSTART_HTML_FILE=\"target1-index.html\"
```

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need. 
I'm a bit foreign with how Phonegap and XCode operate together so I'll try to go through these steps to get what I want.
Thank You!