# Cordova doesn't work with iOS Multiple targets

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Cordova iOS: **3.8.0**
Cordova: **5.1.1**

I have to create two additional targets (with different bundle id) to my project. When I do this, and when I do:

```
$ cordova prepare ios
```

I have this error in my Terminal:

```
could not find -Info.plist file, or config.xml file
```

Do I need to create a different config.xml file for each target? If yes, how should i do this?

---

Steps to do to reproduce the "bug":

1. Create an empty HelloWorld project:

   `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`

   `cordova platforms add ios`
2. Open the project in xcode, duplicate a target.
3. Then do, for example:

   `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

The plugin will not get installed because of the same error.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue. Could you elaborate on duplicating a target? Judging by what you've mentioned, you duplicated the existing target twice, and changed bundle ID on the new targets. Did you change scheme? Is there anything else you did?

Comment: possibly something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469547/how-to-use-different-config-xml-for-different-phonegap-targets-in-xcode)?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently Cordova has problems with multiple targets.

There is a pull request with a fix: https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/pull/219

Until Codova fixes this issue, here's a manual workaround:

1. fetch the patched cordova-lib:

git clone http://github.com/ogoguel/cordova-lib

2. edit */usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/package.json* to use the patched version:

replace:

> "dependencies": {
>
> "cordova-lib": "5.0.0",

with

> "dependencies": {
>
> "cordova-lib": "file:PATH_TO_PATCHED_LIB/cordova-lib/cordova-lib",

(PATH_TO_PATCHED_LIB - should be the absolute path to the cordva-lib folder that you cloned in step 1)

3. update npm installation:

cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova

sudo npm install

Answer (score -1):

Did you check out this tools ? http://tarifa.tools/

It's a powerful layer above cordova that enable multi app IDs generation (i.e. 1 for testing / 1 for the client / 1 for production...)